# Test/consume content of HttpServletResponse outputStream

Tags: java, jax-rs, inputstream, outputstream

I am currently trying to test a function that write in the servlet response outputStream.
The server function looks like:

```
@Context
private HttpServletResponse response;

@GET   
@Path("whatever")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void streamJson() {
    writeJsonInOutputstream(response.getOutputStream());
}
```

I can see it is working by "curl"ing it or saving it as a file using the browser.

To test this function I tried something like in this website.
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/sending_and_receiving_streams_with

```
 try (InputStream stream = client.target(...whatever)
                                 .request()
                                 .get(InputStream.class);) {
        assertNotNull(stream);
        //process stream
 }
```

But sadly the stream is null. (response status is 200). If I try to use a Response then the entity is null.
I can't use the StreamingOutput but am I somehow missing a step?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You produce json but your method signature is void and you want to produce stream

Comment: @HRgiger Switching to octet stream doesn't do the trick. I guess it is not mandatory as the browser and curl can read the response somehow.